# OpenOffice files open with Archive Manager by default

Tags: 14.10, openoffice.org, archive

If I double click a .odt (OpenOffice Document) file that's on a 4TB MyBook USB drive plugged into my router it tries to open it in Archive Manager. I have to right click it, go to "open with..." and click OpenOffice.org Calc.

Can I change the default "Open with..." to OpenOffice Calc like in Windows, or is there something else I have to do to get it to open correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Josh

if you right-click on a (let's say) odt file in nautilus and select "Properties", you can change default opening behaviour in 3-rd tab, the one labeled "Open with", then confirm with "set as default".

Cheers,

Silvia